# Two external monitors for Thinkpad T60

Tags: multiple-monitors

I've got a Thinkpad T60 with Intel 950 graphics. I'd like to connect two external monitors with 2048x1536. If I understand correctly, this will mean that the internal monitor will be off (that graphics card has a limit of 4096x4096 total). Also, I will have to buy a dock (either [Thinkpad Advanced Dock](http://www.thinkwiki.org/wiki/ThinkPad_Advanced_Dock) or [Thinkpad Advanced Mini Dock](http://www.thinkwiki.org/wiki/ThinkPad_Advanced_Mini_Dock)). One of the monitors will be connected to VGA (analog), the other one to DVI-D (digital). I need this to work under Linux.

I know I could also get [Matrox TripleHead2Go](http://www.matrox.com/graphics/en/products/gxm/th2go/) or similar, but I am worried about it not working with Linux.

Will this setup work correctly?

Answer (score 1):

Support for multi-head displays is much improved in recent versions of Ubuntu (10.04+). Editing of config files is no longer necessarily required. However, it is worth checking your hardware specifically.

Answer (score 0):

I heard that you need to fiddle with config files ( Was: https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?pid=268628 ) if you need 2 monitor configs to work before. I am not quite sure that you can get it work with advanced dock and 2 external monitors.

However, there are reports that matrox triplehead2go does work in ubuntu. just note that maximum dimension... (See: http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=619143 )